# how to make new child in firebase realtimedatabase

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

```
val databaseref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
databaseref.child("post")
```

is that a correct way to make child and subchild in the firebase database

Answer (score 0):

This will generate an exception. Because you have not separated by "`;`".

```
val databaseref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
val child = databaseref.child("post)";
```

This will return the child if present, else create a child.

Comment: Semicolons are almost always optional in JavaScript.  Here, they are still not required.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `child(...)` on a `DatabaseReference` creates a reference to a location in the database, but it doesn't actually read of write any data yet.

To create the child, write a valid to the reference:

```
val databaseref=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
databaseref.child("post").set(true);
```